# Entity Framework CodeFirst many to many relationship with additional information

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have the following model :

```
class Contract
{
   string ContractID{get;set;}
   ICollection<Part> Parts{get;set;}
}

class Part
{
   string PartID{get;set;}
   ICollection<Contract> Contracts{get;set;}
}
```

the problem is that the relationship between Part and Contract also contains the following  additional information :

```
class ContractParts
{ 
   Contract{get;set;}
   Part{get;set;}
   Date{get;set;} //additional info
   Price{get;set;} //additional info
}
```

How would I write the Entity Context for this ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In such case you must model your entities this way:

```
public class Contract
{
   public virtual string ContractId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ContractPart> ContractParts { get; set; }
}

public class Part
{
   public virtual string PartId { get;set; }
   public virtual ICollection<ContractPart> ContractParts { get; set; }
}

public class ContractPart
{ 
   public virtual string  ContractId { get; set; }
   public virtual string PartId { get; set; }
   public virtual Contract Contract { get; set; }
   public virtual Part Part { get; set; }
   public virtual string Date { get; set; } //additional info
   public virtual decimal Price { get; set; } //additional info
}
```

In derived context you must define:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<ContractPart>()
               .HasKey(cp => new { cp.ContractId, cp.PartId });

   modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
               .HasMany(c => c.ContractParts)
               .WithRequired()
               .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.ContractId);

   modelBuilder.Entity<Part>()
               .HasMany(p => p.ContractParts)
               .WithRequired()
               .HasForeignKey(cp => cp.PartId);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the good answer!  It helped.  I knew about making the navigation properties virtual, but why did you make the scalar properties virtual?

Comment: It is used for improving change tracking performance when using attached entities.

Comment: Is this true for properties that you don't intend to change (such as the primary key)?

Comment: @Mark: Good question. I never thought about this. I'm not sure if all properties must be virtual to allow this.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka: What do you think? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260306/entity-framework-5-code-first-cyclical-relationship-issues

Comment: @ladislavmrna can you explain why you needed to use fluent? Isn't this all convention based ? Similar answer doesn't use fluent : http://stackoverflow.com/a/7053393/16940

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: Relation configurations should not be necessary - default convention should handle them but configuration of composite key is necessary. If you don't use it you need to use attributes to tell EF about primary key of `ContractPart` class.

Comment: Is there a way to get a surrogate key on the ContractPart ( ContractPartSurrogateKey ) ?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps a better way to do is this answer? [Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

It doesn't require fluent APIs and also sets up the PK on join table.

Comment: What I like about this link is that are some good examples of how to actually Perform updates once your model is in place