# Define model for deep relationships/ nested models

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a db that looks like this:

```
tblUsers
   - UserId
tblRoles
   - RoleId

tblUserRoles
   - UserRoleId
   - RoleId
   - UserId

class User
{
   [Key]
   public virtual int UserId{ get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("UserId")] // how does this tell ef not to map it to the primary key. 
                             It needs to map to UserId which is not defined as a key.??

   public DbSet<UserRole> Roles{ get; set; }
}    

class UserRoles
{
   [Key]
   public virtual int UserRoleId{ get; set; }

   public virtual int UserId{ get; set; }
   public virtual int RoleId{ get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
   Public Role RoleInfo {get; set;}
}

class Role 
{
   [Key] 
   public virtual int RoleId {get; set;}

   public string RoleName {get; set;}
}
```

I don't think this is correct. I need to setup the model where the foreign key is not the primary key but a column in the table.  My question:  How do I define my model and link the relationship between entities without having a primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean how might you link these tables together? I generally I have my Model setup to mirror (for the most part) the table structure of the database. Below is how I would setup the Model. `User` has a collection of `UserRoles` each of which has one `Role` with that record.

```
internal class User
{
    public User()
    {
        UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

internal class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    public int UserRoleId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RoleId")]
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}

internal class Role
{
    public Role()
    {
        UserRoles = new List<UserRole>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

So basically there is a One to Many between User and `UserRole`, and a One to Many between `Role` and `UserRole`

Comment: It compiled but no roles were loaded in to the list.    How is Roles mapped to UserRole in your example?

Comment: @magic-c0d3r Righto, I updated my code sample to have a One to many between User and UserRole and a One to many between UserRole and Role. Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: Why is RoleInfo a collection in UserRole?  any help is great thanks.

Comment: @magic-c0d3r oops had that reversed. I updated my answer (code and comments).

Comment: How does it know to match on UserId and not UserRoleId?

Comment: @magic-c0d3r I believe it is one of the default conventions for EF pocos that their navigation properties will be setup this way. As you can see `User` has a collection of `UserRoles` and `UserRole` has a reference back to its parent `User`. The "Magic" of EF conventions is that the `UserRole` table will have an FK from its `UserId` property to the primary key of `User`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to declared the class `UserRoles` , EF code first will create the relationship and tables needed behind the scene, this is all you need:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles {get;set;}
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users {get;set;}
}
```

then override your `OnModelCreating`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<User>()
    .HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithMany(r => r.Users)
    .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("UserId")
    .MapRightKey("RoleId")
    .ToTable("UserRoles"));
}
```

The only time you need to declare the join table yourself, is if you need a `many-to-many` with payload. Check this post [many-to-many with payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434125/entity-framework-codefirst-many-to-many-relationship-with-additional-information)

Comment: How do I this with just One to Many. If you take out Users from the Role Model?

Comment: @magic-c0d3r , so a `User` has one `Role`? and a `Role`, belongs to many `Users`? check answer edit.

Comment: No a User has many Roles and a Role can belong to Many Users.  But I dont want to show that in my model. Just need Users with many roles to work for now. Unless I have to include Users in the UserRole class

Comment: You are always going to need to include a `Property Reference` from one class to another, even if you end up using a `UserRole` class, your `User` class will still need to have a `Collection` of `UserRole` and your `Role` class will need to have a collection of `UserRole`.