# query with SQL m:n relationships

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I have a quick question with respect to many to many relationships in sql. 
So theoretically i understand that if 2 entities in an ER model have a M:N relationship between them, we have to split that into 2 1:N relationships with the inclusion of an intersection/lookup table which has a composite primary key from both the parent tables. But, my question here is , in addition to the composite primary key, can there be any other extra column added to the composite table which are not in any of the 2 parent tables ? (apart from intersectionTableId, table1ID, table2ID) a 4rth column which is entirely new and not in any of the 2 parent tables ? Please let me know.

Comment: What DBMS is this and how is the intersection table being created?

Comment: Absolutely!  Data about the association BELONGS on such a table. Think about a Customer / Movie rental database.  I want to know what customer checked out what movie as a customer could have many movies and a movie could be checked out by only 1 customer at a time; but I want the history of the movies checked out and know when it's been returned.  The associative table could have a Checkout and a CheckIn date; this would tell me the history and duration of checkouts for a customer and maybe based on movie genera and customer rented movies, a suggestion listing could be created...

Comment: @WEI_DBA, I was using Oracle at the time and it was for a book recommendation table just in case the person couldn't find his/her required book, we wanted to suggest another suitable one, my apologies for the delay in response.

Comment: Thanks a lot @xQbert for clearing this up in my head, I apologize for not having followed up on this, but i'm learning from my past mistakes. Hope you can let that pass.

Comment: @gireesh4manu no problem.Just glad to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a word - yes. It's a common practice to denote properties of the relationship between the two entities.

E.g., consider you have a database storing the details of people and the sports teams they like:

```
CREATE TABLE person (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name VARCHAR(10),
    last_name VARCHAR(10)
);

CREATE TABLE team (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(10)
);
```

A person may like more than one team, which is your classic M:N relationship table. But, you could also add some details to this entity, such as when did a person start liking a team:

```
CREATE TABLE fandom (
    person_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES person(id),    
    team_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES team(id),
    fandom_started DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id, team_id)
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Mureinik. Appreciate it big time. it was basically for a book recommendation feature to suggest alternate books for folks who couldn't find out the required ones.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that by modeling the "relationship" table yourself explicitly (just like your other entities).

Here are some posts about exactly that question.

[Create code first, many to many, with additional fields in association table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050404/create-code-first-many-to-many-with-additional-fields-in-association-table)

[Entity Framework CodeFirst many to many relationship with additional information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434125/entity-framework-codefirst-many-to-many-relationship-with-additional-information)

Comment: thank you @SlimsGhost. i'll go through the links you have suggested.